# Grabbing dropdown selected text when using each()

Tags: jquery, each

I have a load of select dropdowns and I'm trying to grab the selected value for each one using each(). I can't seem to get it right. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```
$('#aTable select option:selected').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());  
});
```

Comment: Should work.. https://jsfiddle.net/8613t1q7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#aTable select').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: @Damien Can you clarify? That should be logging the current value for each select. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, does grab the value, but the value is different from the text. I need the text

Comment: Text method grabs all the drop down text and not the selected value, hence the problem

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Oh, that's basically what you have already. Should work though.

Comment: Doesn't. Grabs all the text for every option

Comment: what is the `$('#aTable select option:selected').length` compared to  `$('#aTable select option').length`?

Comment: 117 which is correct because that's how many dropdowns there are, vs. 10062. I tried to do the console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());, but that didn't work. All that showed up in the console was 117 but no text. In other words, 117 of the same result showed up in the console.

Comment: Correction, just got it working with the code you provided!

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text` to get the selcted text. It works

**Demo:-**

```js
$('#aTable select').each(function(){
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aTable">
  <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```